# Equivalente à função "console.dir()" no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Existe, na linguagem Python (v3.6), alguma função que sirva para exibir atributos e métodos de um objeto, como a `console.dir()` no JavaScript?

---

Eu gostaria de obter um output similar ao do `console.dir` nos navegadores web.
A função `dir` do Python tem um retorno meio "bagunçado", onde é retornado um texto que denota um array, que não informa o que é método e o que é atributo, fora que tal retorno é em estilo texto mesmo, e eu gostaria que em cada linha contivesse apenas um método/atributo, ficando mais fácil para compreender e não se perder.

---

**Exemplificando: Em um cenário onde um objeto gerencia/representa funcionários:**

Atributos e métodos fictícios:

- Demitir: método
- Contratar: método
- Funcionarios: atributo

---

Como a função `dir` do Python retorna:

```
['demitir', 'contratar', 'funcionarios']
```

---

Como eu gostaria que retornasse (mais ou menos):

```
 {
   'demitir':'function...',
   'contratar':'function...',
   'funcionarios': 20
 }
```

---

Estou aberto a sugestões de bibliotecas/recursos de terceiros. Não preciso que seja nativo, só preciso que funcione mais ou menos como eu descrevi. Obrigado.

Comment: Tipo a função [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Como eu consigo formatar o output? Sai uma completa bagunça, tanto no console do Windows como no IDLE.

Comment: Como uma bagunça completa? O resultado é uma lista com os atributos e métodos. O que exatamente você quer dizer com "formatar" e por quê isso não está descrito na pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então acredito que o que precisas é do módulo [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html). Neste módulo existe a função `getmembers` que retorna uma lista de pares nome/valor de todos os membros de um objeto. Para verificar o que é o quê, você pode mapear essa lista para obter o nome e tipo do mesmo.

```
import inspect

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    def method(self):
        pass

foo = Foo()

members = ((name, type(value).__name__) for name, value in inspect.getmembers(foo))

for member in members:
    print(member)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/y5AE77) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/FarSeveralSouthernhairnosedwombat)</sup>

A saída gerada é:

```
('__class__', 'type')
('__delattr__', 'method-wrapper')
('__dict__', 'dict')
('__dir__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__doc__', 'NoneType')
('__eq__', 'method-wrapper')
('__format__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__ge__', 'method-wrapper')
('__getattribute__', 'method-wrapper')
('__gt__', 'method-wrapper')
('__hash__', 'method-wrapper')
('__init__', 'method')
('__init_subclass__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__le__', 'method-wrapper')
('__lt__', 'method-wrapper')
('__module__', 'str')
('__ne__', 'method-wrapper')
('__new__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__reduce__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__reduce_ex__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__repr__', 'method-wrapper')
('__setattr__', 'method-wrapper')
('__sizeof__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__str__', 'method-wrapper')
('__subclasshook__', 'builtin_function_or_method')
('__weakref__', 'NoneType')
('method', 'method')
('x', 'int')
('y', 'int')
```

Perceba que os métodos `__init__` e `method` são do tipo `method`, indicando que são métodos e os atributos possuem os respectivos tipos, `int`, `str`, `dict`, etc.